# Php userprofile that show on the side when you log in

Tags: php

How do I code this on php or what is it called this type of userprofile?

[image]

I got this on Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

That is the place where the users avatar is displayed. Data shown there is being pulled from a database, possibly a users table. What is being shown by gmail is more of design than back end(in your case php). php for instance will pull the user's records for instance username and image. How you decide to display is upto you.